# Ajax timeout but server side not terminate

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I'm using jQuery and use $.ajax to send out request.

My computer is pretty slow(which can be fixed by adding updating the memory),

and the request times out frequently.

But I've found that although it's timeout,

process at server side doesn't terminate.

Is is normal or something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using HTTP (stateless protocol). When $.ajax hits a request to the server, Server takes long time to complete the job and $.ajax goes for timeout, Still the job in server will be running. (Which is Normal because we are using HTTP).

The $.ajax timeout is only for client not for server.